# Why does the code give segmentation fault on running?

Tags: c++, string, io, segmentation-fault, stack

On running the code by commenting the stack statement, it produces correct output, but on declaring the stack it shows segmentation fault. Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t;
    char *expr;

    stack < string > inp_stack;
    // queue <int> op_queue;

    cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {

        cin >> expr;
        cout << expr << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're writing through an uninitialized pointer. Where do you think it points to?

Comment: initialize variables before using it

Answer (score 1):

```
char *expr;
cin >> expr;
```

`expr` is an uninitialized (invalid) pointer, using of which results in *undefined behavior*.

In case you want to read `t` words from the input stream, use `std::string` object instead:

```
int t = 0;
std::cin >> t;

std::string expr;
while (t > 0 && std::cin >> expr) {
    std::cout << expr << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It segfaults because you are accessing an uninitialized pointer.  `expr` is never initialized so your program segfaults as soon as you access it.

You either need to allocate memory for `expr` or change it to a fixed size array.